# Contravariant rank-2 tensor transformation in index notation

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, conventions, notation

I'm slightly confused about the placement of upper and lower indices for the transformation of a rank-2 contravariant tensor.

A contravariant rank-2 tensor transforms as $$M' = \Lambda M \Lambda^{T}$$.
In index notation, $\Lambda = \Lambda^{i}{}_{j}$ and $\Lambda^{T} = (\Lambda^{T})^{i}{}_{j}$. Therefore, I assumed the above transformation would be written

$$\tag{1}(M')^{ab} = \Lambda^{a}{}_{\mu}M^{\mu\nu}(\Lambda^{T})^{\nu}{}_{b}$$,

however, it appears in the literature as

$$ \tag{2} (M')^{ab} = \Lambda^{a}{}_{\mu}M^{\mu\nu}(\Lambda^{T})_{\nu}{}^{b}$$ .

I know that $(\Lambda^{T})^{\nu}{}_{b}$ and $(\Lambda^{T})_{\nu}{}^{b}$ differ by a multiplication of two metrics, so these are not the same matrix. However, the only reason I can see to use (2) over (1) is so that a contraction is over an upper and lower index.

Any help in explaining why it's (2) that we use, not (1), would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or for answering the question; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110872/discussion-on-question-by-john-contravariant-rank-2-tensor-transformation-in-ind).

Comment: The chat's been moved to the comments, I've just got one final query if that's ok